# run a script at boot before login screen

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, startup, boot

I'm trying to run a script at boot on on orange thin device using Armbian Ubuntu22 OS that will check if the device is connected to the internet or not. If it isn't, the script will run the "armbian-config" command to open a system configuration screen and i will be able to edit the network configuration through it, the script is running fine but i can't execute it to run at boot before user login screen.

here is the ways that i've tried:
`$ sudo nano /usr/share/check_network.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 1 google.com
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

  echo "configure your network" | bash -c "read; armbian-config"
fi
```

then i added the script's path to the `lightdm.conf` file:
`$ sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=/usr/share/check_network.sh
```

i also tried to add it to
`$ sudo nano /usr/share/xgreeters/slick-greeter.desktop`

```
Exec=/bin/bash /usr/share/check_network.sh
```

and
`$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

```
/usr/share/check_network.sh
```

and
`$ sudo nano /home/mydevice/.config/autostart/check_network.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sudo /usr/share/check_network.sh
StartupNotify=false
```

and i didn't forget to use `chmod +x` with the files,
but the script didn't start at boot with anyone of these, i'm missing something somewhere, any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Armbian a Systemd thing (Yech!)?
If that's the case maybe try setting up a service file /etc/systemd/system/check_net.service as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=check_net
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/check_network.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run the following command to enable it on boot:

`systemctl enable check_net`

Comment: i tried setting up a service file but didn't execute the script, i checked the status of it with systemctl status check_net.service and it is running and active.

Comment: I would suggest changing to a different init system for a mobile device.  Systemd is just ridiculous on so many levels.  Good luck.

Comment: i already did my different needs such as starting a specific app and user login at boot using lightdm now i only need the script of network checking to work at boot because the configuration that i need shouldn't allow me to access linux system after boot at all.. anyway i'll see if i can change the init system if i still stuck here..thanks a lot! :)